# Why isn't 'for line in file' copying all lines in my text file?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, text-files

I wrote some code to pull certain lines from a large text file and noticed some strange things missing, so I ran the following code to make sure the for loop was actually hitting every line in the file:

```
xf=open("bigFile.txt", r)
xxf=open("newFile.txt",w)
for line in xf:
  xxf.write(line)
```

This ends up not copying all the lines for some reason.  Could anyone tell me what I'm not understanding or doing wrong?  It ends up only making a file about 60-70% as big as it should be?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for the input skrrgwasme & Shreevardhan. To clarify, my ultimate goal is not just to copy the file, in my working code I put some comparison operators before writing the line, for example:

```
for line in xf:
 firstChar=line[:1]
 if firstChar==1:
   xxf.write(line)
```

That is why I am using the "for line in file".    Should I do this some other way?

Comment: you could try to call `xxf.flush()` at some point. and check the answer of [skrrgwasme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615940/skrrgwasme) below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your file. There's no guarantee that buffers you're writing into are being flushed to disk before your script exits. You can do this very easily by using a context manager:

```
with open("bigFile.txt") as xf, open("newFile.txt", "w") as xxf:
    for line in xf:
        xxf.write(line)
```

In your current code, you would write `xf.close()` and `xxf.close()`, but using a context manager like this will handle it for you, and even close the files if an exception occurs.

Also, if you really are simply copying the file, you can also use [shutil.copyfile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I write it exactly as you have it, I am still not getting all the lines copied. And you are right, I'm not simply copying, but am testing the above code, with no comparison operators to make sure it's getting every line.  Using your code above and my original code, when I run it on a 400MB file it spits back a file that is only about 275MB.  It's really making me scratch my head.

Comment: @codezilla Have you looked at the output file to confirm there are missing lines, or just looked at the file size? It could be getting written out in a more dense encoding than the source file.

Comment: yes I've looked at the files and the copy is only around 550k lines, while the original file is about 800k lines.  I really cant figure out why a simple "for x in file" loop wouldn't copy the file line for line?  Am I understanding this loop correctly, that if I write the for loop like I did in my example it should copy each line of the file?

Comment: @codezilla Yes, you're understanding the loop correctly. As long as the file is properly closed, it should copy everything. Try opening both files in Notepad++ to check the character count and see if some of your lines are being accidentally combined. If the character counts match, you can enable "View all Characters" in the source file to see if you have mixed Windows/Linux line endings that could cause Python to miss line endings.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file, it's better to use functions from `shutil` module like `copyfile()`, `copy()`, or `copy2()`.

For example

```
from shutil import copyfile, copy2
copyfile('bigFile.txt', 'newFile.txt')
```

or

```
copy2('bigFile.txt', 'newFile.txt')
```

Comment: Hey Shreevardhan, thanks for your answer, however I don't think this is going to work for my situation bc I am trying to do some comparisons before copying each line in my production code.  Sorry for the misunderstanding, I tried to clarify further above.